# How I can compare two text files?

Tags: batch-file, compare

I saved two .txt  (Ej: File1.txt, File2.txt)
How should I compare the text for an specific line:

```
(
echo echo example
echo echo example
echo echo example
) > File1.txt

(
echo echo example
echo echo example
echo echo file example
) > File2.txt
```

Return in this case false because the line 3 its not equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fc file1.txt file2.txt>nul
if errorlevel 1 (echo different) else (echo same)
```

fundamental. run `fc` to compre the files, and suppress output. `errorlevel` is established =0 if same, else different.